Elliptic integral of complex argument with value greater than unity
I need to compute the elliptic integral with a complex argument.
I know that there exists a formula for the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind for complex arguments, as follows from P.F.Byrd, M.D. Friedman:

However, my real and imaginary parts of the complex argument are outside the unity boundary. In this case, does the formula above still hold? If not, is there any other way to get the real and imaginary values of the elliptic integral with a complex argument when both its real and imaginary parts are greater than unity?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

In the elliptic integrals
$$\int_a^b f(\sqrt{1-x^2},\sqrt{1-k^2 x^2}) \ dx $$
the Landen transform
$$ k \ x \to y, \quad a \to k \ a, \quad b \to k \  b , \quad dx \to \frac{dy}{k} $$
yields
$$\int_{a \, k}^{b\, k} \ f\ \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k} y^2}, \quad \sqrt{1-y^2}\right) \ \frac{dy}{k} = \int_{a \, k}^{b\, k} \ g\ \left(\sqrt{1-y^2} , \quad \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k} y^2} \right) \ \frac{dy}{k}$$
with the effect, that there exists a formal group table of modulus transformation formulas for the  elliptic functions, the trigononometric field of the  inverse of the integral, connecting functions of modulus $k, \ k', \ i k, \ 1/k$, the elementary modular transformations.
